# convert MultiSelect to a Single Line select

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

so at the moment I have a dataGideView with multiSelect disabled. Although that is the case when I drag click the computer does not count that as a cell click. How do I get it so that a drag click counts the first cell it hits as a cell click.

Answer (score 0):

MouseClick or Click will trigger on release. If you only want to check when the mouse is clicked, use [MouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want something to happen when they click (before release), you will have to subscribe to the MouseDown event of each child control, and do whatever you want. To avoid repetition, you will have to create custom controls, and handle the event within the class (if possible).

Comment: I want to know where it clicked

Comment: From the link: "Occurs when the mouse pointer is over the control and a mouse button is pressed."

MouseDown will let you know which control was clicked as it will be the control that triggered the event.